# Caching objects in a RESTful WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, rest

I'm looking for a way to cache objects in memory with a RESTful WCF service. The service is completely stateless and is hosted outside of an IIS. I want to implement the caching by myself, so memcached isn't an option.

Right now I'm thinking of hosting a separate stateful `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` that does all the caching. It'll communicate with the rest of the WCF methods through a separate port or by some other means. However I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution to my problem. Has anyone got any tips?

Comment: A service is stateless that's fine and dandy. But but when you say "set up another stateful sevice host", that's missleading. A service host is stateful ipso facto because it hosts a service. Why not use the same host to in-memory-cache the image streams? I don't see the point of having two seperate service hosts.

Comment: @anas: You're right of course, but how else can I keep something in memory when the service is entirely stateless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion between stateless service and a stateful host and how the two can interact.

In this code sample I demonstrate conceptually how an in-memory singleton (Caching mechanism, I refer to as `CachingProvider` henceforth) can be referenced by both the service class (the service instance more precisely during the lifecycle of the request) and the service host (in this case I chose it to be a **Console Application**)

**I assume here, the service interface and class are both located within the console applicaiton project that hosts the service.**

In this simple example, my primitive `CachingProvider` class basically acts as a counter of how many service calls are made to the GetData method, and the service host will poll the `CachingProvider` every 5 seconds to get the count of service calls made so far.

*note: you can use the WCFTestClient utility to test this quickly.*

**Disclaimer:** *I by no means suggest that a complex Caching mechanism be implemented as simply as in this sample, this code is merely for demosntration purposes.*

```
namespace ServiceHostConsole
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public TestService()
        {
            CachingProvider.CallCount++;
        }

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }

    //For demonstration purposes only
    static class CachingProvider
    {
        static CachingProvider()
        {
            //private static constructor can initialize 
            //static cacheable resources
            _callCounter = 0; //Trivial example of initialization
        }

        private static int _callCounter;
        public static int CallCount
        {
            set { _callCounter = value; }
            get { return _callCounter; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), new Uri("http://localhost/TestService")))
            {
                host.Open();

                //Example how the ServiceHost can report on a persistent in-memory object that is being
                //updated each time the service is called.
                new Timer(state => Console.WriteLine("# of service calls: {0}", CachingProvider.CallCount), null, 0, 5000);

                Console.Read();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand now. Good example, and thanks for the clarification.